# MS-SQL | Accessing one table multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are selling printers and ink. We are switching our labeling software and want to implement a database. 
On our labels are safety instructions. Each instruction has a unique identifier and we have have these instructions in several languages. Each ink has about 6-12 instructions.

Now I've designed a database. You'll find the tables at the bottom of this post.

Is it possible to get a ink and the several safety instructions responding to it?

```
INK
i_id
i_name

INSTRUCTION
in_id
in_text

INSTRUCTION_IDENTIFIER
ii_id
ii_name

LANGUAGES
l_id
l_name

INSTRUCTION_LANGUAGE_IDENTIFIER
ili_id
fk_in_id
fk_ii_id
fk_l_id

SUM_TABLE
st_id
fk_i_id
fk_ii_id_1
fk_ii_id_2
fk_ii_id_3
fk_ii_id_4
fk_ii_id_5
fk_ii_id_6
fk_ii_id_7
fk_ii_id_8
fk_ii_id_9
fk_ii_id_10
fk_ii_id_11
fk_ii_id_12
```

Comment: Can you please format better, this is very hard to read...

Comment: what is `fk_s_id` in table `INSTRUCTION_LANGUAGE_IDENTIFIER`?

Comment: @EBS_EDV :  Ya you can get it using join statements.

Comment: Have you tried? You obviously know about foreign keys and the relationships between tables, have you attempted to write a query to do this?

Comment: Having 12 ids in the same row looks suspicious. Can't you have id + sequence number instead? Then you don't have to change database structure if you get 13th id to add. Also there's probably something missing since it feels like e.g. language is not connected to anything else.

Comment: Hungarian notation has said goodbye in the nineties. Looking at the schema makes your head spin...

Comment: Sorry for the formatting error :/

Comment: @Paolo: I want to use fk_s_id as foreign key to l_id from language_id. That was a typo...

Comment: @Elliveny: Yes, I've tried it, but it seems that I have a blockade in my mind...I dont know how to "replace" the ID with the text from the other table.

Comment: @JamesZ: That was just my idea how to implement our scenario...the language is connected to the instruction_language_identifier. I just made a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-joins.htm

you need to learn about joins to bring info from other tables 
it would be something like

```
Select sum.*,ins1.name,ins2.name, ..... ins12.name
from SUM_TABLE sum 
inner join INSTRUCTION ins1  on ins1.ii_id =  sum.fk_ii_id_1 
inner join INSTRUCTION ins2  on ins2.ii_id =  sum.fk_ii_id_2 
....     

inner join INSTRUCTION ins12  on ins12.ii_id =  sum.fk_ii_id_12
```

you should rethink your strategy about the sum table since if you in the future require a 13 id you REALLY don't want to recreate the table

Answer (score 0):

i don't work on ink & co so my suggestion may be flawed but from your description i would go with a different solution:

```
INK
i_id
i_name

INSTRUCTION
in_id
in_text
l_id

LANGUAGES
l_id
l_name

INK_INSTRUCTION
i_id
in_id
ii_position
```

should you need more instruction rows for any ink you don't have to modify database structure (as pointed out by @JamesZ).

if this is something you will rely upon for (possibly) years in the future in a software you are going to sell, imho you should pay for support to define database structure.
the wrong database structure can make things a nightmare to use and maintain and if you start wrong then you will see costs raise (difficult development, difficult maintenance, complex upgrades, complex migration).